# How to programmatically insert a string at the end of some file?

Tags: files, insert

How to silently (in background) create a new line at the end of a specific file, say `/path/to/file.txt` (which is not necessarily a visiting file and is not necessarily already open in emacs) and insert some string (say `xyz`) in that new line and then to save the file after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `append-to-file` and `write-region` functions, for example,

```
~ $ echo hello > file.txt
~ $ emacs --batch --eval '(append-to-file "xyz\n" nil "file.txt")'
~ $ cat file.txt
hello
xyz
~ $
```

See also [`(info "(elisp) Writing to Files")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-to-Files.html).

Comment: Thanks, hence the answer is (append-to-file "xyz\n" nil "/path/to/file.txt").